# HOW TO - SQL join to GET EXTRA row(s) from 2 tables based on 1 common table mapping

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following tables

```
UserRights - This table contains extra role selected for the user has been defined. 
RoleRights - Default roles defined by the users
UserRole - To map the user and their default role
Roles - Role name (ID = Primary Key)
UserMaster - Primary User table (ID = Primary Key)
ModuleMaster - For Module (ID = Primary Key)
FunctionMaster - For Function (ID = Primary Key, ModuleID = FK)
SubFunctionMaster - For SubFunction (ID = Primary Key, FunctionID = FK)
```

CONDITION: User has to be part of a ROLE, only then they can select extra roles if required.

```
| UserMaster |
|------------|
| ID (PK)    |


| UserRights |
|---------------------|
| UserID (FK)         |
| ModuleID  (FK)      |
| FunctionID (FK)     |
| SubFunctionID (FK)  |


| RoleRights    |
|---------------------|
| RoleID (FK)         |
| ModuleID  (FK)      |
| FunctionID (FK)     |
| SubFunctionID (FK)  |


| UserRole      |
|---------------|
| UserID (FK)   |
| RoleID (FK)   |
```

Now, in the table **UserRights** we have the combined result set of data available in **RoleRights** table and additionally **SubFunctionID** grants provided for that particular user.

We need to list only those rows which is additionally available in the table **UserRights** for all users and skip the matching rows which is available in both **UserRights** and **RoleRights** for the particular user's role to which they are part of based on the mapping between table **UserRole** and **RoleRights** and **UserRights**

Comment: Using keyword 'EXCEPT' solved the issue, but is the approach correct?